# using jQuery to call webMethod returns HTML... webMethod not called at all

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, webmethod

I'm using VisualStudio 2008 and have a method on an ASPX page I am trying to call with javascript using jQuery as shown below. I am just getting the page's HTML back. The webmethod is not called. Interestingly, if I change the name of the webMethod to call in the javascript, I still get back the HTML. Not an error saying the webMethod cannot be found.

I've tried changing the data argument to "{ 'dummy':0 }", but that doesn't help.

I've used this strategy without problem in a new VS 2010 app, but can't seem to get it to work on an existing app in VS 2008 that I am adding a page to. (trying to add a twist to an old app) I've looked at what firebug is telling me in firefox, and all looks right.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

C# WebMethod decalaration:

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static string getQuestionnaires(int dummy)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("getQuestionnaires called");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "dbo.ws_GetPSQuestionnaire";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable dtQuestionnairesRaw = Utilities.ReturnDataSet(command).Tables[0];

        DataTable dtQuestionnaires = new DataTable();
        dtQuestionnaires.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("questionnaireID", typeof(int)));
        dtQuestionnaires.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name"));

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtQuestionnairesRaw.Rows)
        {
            DataRow drNew = dtQuestionnaires.NewRow();
            drNew["questionnaireID"] = dr["questionnaireID"];
            drNew["name"] = Utilities.RemoveHTMLTags(dr["name"].ToString());
            dtQuestionnaires.Rows.Add(drNew);
        }
        dtQuestionnaires.AcceptChanges();

        return (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtQuestionnaires, Formatting.Indented));
    }
```

I am calling it with this javascript. My error function is ALWAYS called.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/crs4/admin/editPSQuestionnaire.aspx/getQuestionnaires",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{ 'dummy':'0' }",
            dataType: "json",
            success: populateQuestionnaires,
            error: AjaxFailed
        });
    });
```

Comment: "{ 'dummy':'0' }", 
 should be valid JSON notation in the string '{ "dummy":"0"}', - you also have to have specific web.config options set to call page methods (as opposed to web service methods only).  Can you explain why you manually serialize vs letting the .net do that for you by returning a valid item such as a list?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Don't I need to pass valid JSON to the web method? How would I pass it otherwise? Once this is working, I will have other methods I wish to call with different parameters accordingly.

Comment: what I posted was for the purpose of simply getting it to work. I'll use a function that accepts an array of parameters for use elsewhere on my page.

Comment: check the URL for the 401 error

Answer (score 1):

Let's get this down to very simple to verify your configuration:

create a simple class to return:

```
public class myReturn
{
    /// web service/webmethod needs 0 parameter constructor
    public myReturn()
    {
    }
    public myReturn(string returnValue)
    { 
        ReturnValue = returnValue;
    }
    public string ReturnValue;
}
```

declare your web method to use the class:

```
[WebMethod()]      
public static myReturn getQuestionnaires(int dummy)      
{
   return new myReturn("howdy");
}
```

Call it:

```
//set up the ajax with error so we see what is going on.
// the following syntax requires jquery 1.5 or later for the
// converters used for asp.net
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    converters: {
        "json jsond": function(msg) {
            return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var errorMessage = ("Ajax error - " + this.url + " | "
           + textStatus + " | " + errorThrown + " | " 
           + xhr.statusText + " | " + xhr.status);
        alert(errorMessage);
    }
});

var pString = '{"dummy":0}';
$.ajax({
    data: pString,
    url: "/crs4/admin/editPSQuestionnaire.aspx/getQuestionnaires",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

EDIT: you might need this in the web config:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>
```

Comment: Okay, I created a new empty page to run this test against called "Tester". Changed the URL to use that page instead. Got this error: Ajax error - /crs4/admin/Tester.aspx/getQuestionnaires | parsererror | SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character | OK | 200

Comment: If you run the debugger to the line where it returns, did it actually get the 0 to the method as expected? or simply change it to another number like 2 in the pString if that is confusing :)

Comment: Also, be sure you have your web.config file set up for this...calling aspx.net page methods - lots of articles on that available.  I make a wild assumption about 3.5 and not 2.0 .net but if you use 2.0 you will need script manager as well.

Comment: One other thought, you are simply returning a string and you might change the dataType to "jsond"

Comment: The web app has an asmx page included for web services. So I would think that the web.config file is fine. It is .net 3.5. I put in a diagnostics.debug.writeline as the first line in the web method and it never writes anything. Adding a breakpoint on the return line doesn't get hit either. It looks like the web method isn't being called here either. Changed the dataType in the .ajaxSetup to jsond and I get the same error.

Comment: I've been playing and I noticed that if I change the URL to something completely unrelated, I still get the same error. So something in the way the .net is capturing it is not resolving properly. This is driving me NUTS! I tried creating a new website under VS 2008 and updating the default page. It wouldn't even compile... giving an error about not being able to load some assembly. :( I'm going to try adding my calls to the existing .asmx page and just try calling that page. I was hoping to keep stuff related to my current page WITH my current page.

Comment: There are configuration settings SPECIFIC to page methods as opposed to asmx - don't have them right at hand but I know that can be an issue.

Comment: Do you have this in your code behind using:  using System.Web.Services;

Comment: Do you NOT have this in a master page? issues there exist if it is in one.

Comment: Not on a master page. I do have the using System.Web.Services line. It wouldn't compile without.

Comment: See my edit regarding web.config.  Also, go to design view, drag a scriptmanager control onto the page - remove it and visual studio should update your web.config, kind of a shot in the dark but...

Comment: It added a bunch of assemblies to the web.config. Thought for sure that would solve the problem, but it hasn't. I'm at a complete loss. I'll look for other ways to do what I want to do.

Comment: I think I just discovered my problem. Part of my solution has old projects in it that were never upgraded so the app is running in a .net 2 pool. I'm going to see if I can upgrade these items.

Comment: Yes, if it is running 2.0 you would need the script manager, or upgrade them as you say.

Comment: I think I've been looking at this all wrong. I've been so closely watching the Net portion to see what was being passed that I didn't see what was being posted to the Console. I'm getting 401 Unauthorized errors. The page doesn't require IIS authentication to run and it's the same page as the source all on localhost. Not sure why Im getting this error. Working on this aspect.   This was so much easier on my new VS 2010 project. Can't believe how difficult it is to retrofit an existing VS 2008 app.

Comment: Gave up trying to get this to work. Convinced people to let me upgrade the solution and related solutions to VS 2010 and .net 4. Once I did that, everything worked as expected. I don't know how people get this to work on VS 2008 .net 3.5.

Comment: @AaronBratcher - I highly suspect a configuration issue was at play here.  Anyway, glad you are moving forward with your project.