# Webmethod never called, instead I get html of page back

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am sure I am missing something obvious here. I have read various posts on SO:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
[using jQuery to call webMethod returns HTML... webMethod not called at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194784/using-jquery-to-call-webmethod-returns-html-webmethod-not-called-at-all)

but cannot see what I have wrong. Any attempt to call the webmethod results in a full HTML page being returned. I am using .NET 4.51 WebForms. My script is:

```
  <script>     
        $(function() {
            alert('here');

            //Get the list of files already uploaded for this user
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Maintenance/DesignerImages2/UserExistingImagesGet",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('success');
                    var data2 = data.hasOwnProperty("d") ? data.d : data;
                    alert(data2);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('error');
                    var data2 = data.hasOwnProperty("d") ? data.d : data;
                    alert(data2);
                }
            });

            alert('here2');
        });

    </script>
```

and the code behind for /Maintenance/DesignerImages2 is:

```
  [WebMethod]
        public static string UserExistingImagesGet()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

and I have the following in Web.config:

```
 <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions" />
    </httpModules>
```

Comment: are u using mvc or web form?

Comment: As per my original post "...I am using .NET 4.51 WebForms...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `url` value to "/Maintenance/DesignerImages2.aspx/UserExistingImagesGet".

Comment: Doh!! I am so used to pretty URL's I missed that. That fixed it, thanks.